# Breaking apart url and passing parts in MVC

Tags: php, model-view-controller

I am trying to create an MVC application and am currently working on the Bootstrap file. I get the URL and explode it then assign the parts to the Controller Method and Method arguments. But, I can't find a way to pass multiples arguments to the method.

mysite/newuser/login/user_name/user_pass

```
newuser -> Controler of the site
login   -> currently used method

user_name -> first argument
user_pass -> second_argument
```

For example

```
$url = "mysite/newuser/login/user_name/user_pass";

$path = expload('/',$url);


$this->controler = $path[0];
$this->method    = $path[1];
```

For the arguments I create a second array like this:

```
// Set the substring path as method properties
if (isset($path[2])) {

    $this->url_sub_path = $path[2];

    $sub_path = explode('/', $this->url_sub_path);
     if (isset($sub_path)) {

         $this->model_properties = $sub_path;
```

When i assign the controllers a set

```
$site_controler = $this->controler;
include CONTROLER.$site_controler . '.php';

$new_instans = new $site_controler();
```

But the problem is here:

```
$site_method = $this->model;
$new_instans->{$site_method}($this->model_properties);
```

`$this->model_properties` is Array

if the function is:

```
public function login($user_name,$user_pass){
    // some code
}
```

I need to pass the url properties they are Array and I have two variables in my function
The idea is to convert the array to variables

Or you could pass an idea in how to pass arguments from URL to my model

Answer (score 0):

Try this function: http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.call-user-func-array.php

```
call_user_func_array ($new_instans->{$site_method} , $this->model_properties )
```

Answer (score 0):

If, as you say, `$this->model_properties` is an array, you can do one of two things.

**Case 1:** Maintain the function declaration, and access the array's elements before calling the function.

The `login()` function (maintain it's declaration):

```
public function login($user_name,$user_pass){
 // some code
}
```

To call the function, do this:

```
$array = $this->model_properties;
$param1 = $array[0]; //The numeric index may vary, depending on how this array was populated
$param2 = $array[1];
$new_instans->{$site_method}($param1, $param2);
```

---

**Case 2:** Change the function declaration to receive an array, and access the array's elements inside the function.

The `login()` function, change the declaration:

```
public function login($arrayParams){
    //Access the parameters like this
    $param1 = $arrayParams[0]; //The numeric index may vary, depending on how this array was populated
    $param2 = $arrayParams[1];

    //The rest of your code...
}
```

To call the function simply pass the array, as you're already doing:

```
$new_instans->{$site_method}($this->model_properties);
```

---

Independently of which version you choose to solve your problem, the important part is this:

```
$param1 = $array[0];
$param2 = $array[1];
```

Here, you assign the content of the array's elements of index `0` and `1` to a variable, allowing you to treat those values independently.